# Dynamic Programming Problem - Maximize Profit by Selling Stocks

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am looking at this code challenge:

> You are selling stocks over n days and you have x number of stocks.
>
> x = y<sub>1</sub> + y<sub>2</sub> + ... + y<sub>n</sub> denoting the number of stocks you sell per day over n days.
>
> There is a list of default prices for each day p[1..n] and a list of selling deduction f[0..x].
>
> Selling deduction depends on how many stocks you sell at a time hence 0 to x.
>
> Actual price per day depends on how many stocks you sell.
>
> For instance, p[1] is 500 and f[120] is 60. If you have 200 stocks and you sell 120 on day 1.
>
> ```
>                        Profit = 120 * (500 - 60) = 50400
> ```
>
> The deduction carries on into subsequent days, so if you sell the remaining stocks on day 2 with p[2] = 300 and f[80] = 40.
>
> ```
>                        Profit = 80 * (300 - 40 - 60) = 16000
> ```

I'm trying to maximize total profit by deciding how many stocks to sell on each day.

I'm not very good at DP problems and have only practiced the traditional problems. I'm getting kind of stuck on this one. I think the approach might use a 3D array with x, n, and p being number of stocks, number of days, and price on that day after the deductions from previous days and the day of if applicable.

I'm trying to figure out the recurrence first for P(x,i,p) denoting maximum profit by selling x shares by day i with p being the price of stocks on day i, but I'm getting stuck as well trying to figure out patterns by working with small examples.

How can I approach this?

Comment: In the example you provided, if you don't sell anything if you don't sell anything on day one, did you get `60` deductions of the first day on the second day? Does your total profit be `200 * (300 - 40 - 60)`? or does deduction change regarding what you sold on day 1? If so, how does it changes?

Comment: If you don't sell anything, there won't be any deductions. If you decide to sell everything on day 2 instead, the profit will be 200 * (300 - f[200]). When calculating the profit on day i, the deductions only carry over if you sell anything on day anywhere between 1 and (i - 1).

Answer (score 0):

One simple `recursive` that could solve this problem in `O(x * n)` is like bellow (Where `x` is the total amount of stocks and `n` is the total number of days) :

```
p = [100, 200, 90, 190]
f = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5]


def max_profit(stocks, day):
    if day == 1:
        return stocks * (p[day - 1] - f[stocks - 1]), [stocks]
    max = 0
    history = []
    for i in range(0, stocks + 1):
        prev_profit, prev_history = max_profit(stocks - i, day - 1)
        profit = prev_profit + i * (p[day - 1] * f[stocks - 1])
        if profit > max:
            max = profit
            history = prev_history
            history.append(i)
    return max, history


print(max_profit(7, 4))
```

In this algorithm I've considered all the ways that is possible to sell stock, I mean 0 share , 1 share, 2 share , .... x shares, and then called `max_profit` for previouse day recursively.